# Como obtenho o access_token quando faço login com Facebook no MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

Quando crio um projeto `MVC5` o `Visual Studio` automaticamente cria um site para mim com opção de login por Facebook, Google... Só preciso habilitar no arquivo `"Startup.Auth.cs"`.

Mas ele faz o login direto e eu não sei como pegar o `access_token`, gostaria de salvar o token para poder fazer requests.

Como obtenho o `access_token`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma instancia do `FacebookAuthenticationOptions` e configurar o `Provider`. O `Provider` contem um evento chamado `OnAuthenticated` que ocorre quando você é autenticado.

```
var facebookOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
    {
        OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:access_token", context.AccessToken, ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"));

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    },

    // pode informar o id e secret diretamente ou incluir no AppSettings
    AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppId"],
    AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebook:AppSecret"]
};

app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions);
```

No código acima eu estou acessando o `access_token` por `context.AccessToken` e adicionando no `Claims` do usuário que fez o login. Este é um bom local para armazenar informações do usuário enquanto estiver logado.

Para ler este valor em alguma parte do seu código utilize:

```
var owinContext = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
var authentication = owinContext.Authentication;
var user = autentication.User;
var claim = (user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("urn:facebook:access_token");

string accessToken;
if (claim != null)
    accessToken = claim.Value;
```

Para simplificar todo este processo você pode criar propriedades em um `BaseController` e fazer com que todos os seus `Controllers` herdem deste novo `Controller`.

O `BaseController` pode ser:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IOwinContext CurrentOwinContext
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
        }
    }

    public IAuthenticationManager Authentication
    {
        get
        {
            return CurrentOwinContext.Authentication;
        }
    }

    public new ClaimsPrincipal User
    {
        get
        {
            return Authentication.User;
        }
    }

    public ClaimsIdentity Identity
    {
        get
        {
            return Authentication.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        }
    }

    public string FacebookAccessToken
    {
        get
        {
            var claim = Identity.FindFirst("urn:facebook:access_token");

            if (claim == null)
                return null;

            return claim.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

E para usar o `access_token` em seu `Controller` você apenas vai precisar acessar a propriedade `FacebookAccessToken`.

```
string accessToken = FacebookAccessToken;
```

---

É possível obter outros valores como

```
context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:username",
    context.User.Value<string>("username"), ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"));

context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("urn:facebook:name",
    context.User.Value<string>("name"), ClaimValueTypes.String, "Facebook"));
```

Note que alguns valores não estarão presentes caso o `Scope` não seja informado. Para obter o e-mail você precisa incluir o `Scope`

```
facebookOptions.Scope.Add("email");
```